# events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

Tags: set, command, arguments

"connect-redis": "latest",
"connect-redis-multiple": "^0.1.2",
"multiple-redis": "1.0.9",
"redis": "latest"

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    at parseError (D:\FyComputing\Dev\Projets\FyCommerce\node_modules\redis-pars
er\lib\parser.js:193:12)
    at parseType (D:\FyComputing\Dev\Projets\FyCommerce\node_modules\redis-parse
r\lib\parser.js:303:14)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when I add a store with a position everything is registered on the data base but the server drops and it gives this error.